# company using IPFS in their application

Tags: ipfs

I am learning IPFS these days and curious about if any company is using IPFS to save data. When we upload file into IPFS, we get a hash and can use the hash to get access to the file content. But in our application, we may want to update the file. Do we just grab the file and update the content?

Answer (score 0):

> But in our application, we may want to update the file. Do we just grab the file and update the content?

You would probably want to use [IPNS](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/ipns/). (InterPlanetary Naming System)

Files and objects in IPFS are addressed by their content, meaning the address (i.e. the hash) would change if you changed the file. This would mean updating any references to that address on each file update, which would be a pain.

To get around this you'd use IPNS to create a stable address that points to the latest version/hash of the file, therefore removing the need to update any references each time the file is changed.

Full link to docs: https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/ipns/